# Nativescript (angular) TabView navigate away and then back without error

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript, tabview, routerlink

I am able to successfully navigate away from a tabview, but when I navigate back I get the following error:

```
CONSOLE ERROR
file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1743:28:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot reattach
ActivatedRouteSnapshot with a different number of children
```

then I can no longer navigate anywhere.

How can I navigate back to a tab view successfully?

Comment: This must be on a specific senario, so could you please share a Playground example where we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I was unable to produce a playground example for it in Playground as the tab view was not working and/or navigating properly. Here is the problem in more specific details.  I have a radlistview in a tab.  I tap a single item to go to a detail view for the item. This navigation is done via an nsRouterLink `[nsRouterLink]="['/details']"` this work fine, but when tapping the back button via navigation to go back to the tab view, i get the error above.  You helped me previously with the swiping of list view items.  basically I am trying to put that radlistview in a tab view